# What does "canonical" mean in vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, terminology, inner-products

I was watching this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDkwklFGMfo

And the professor is talking about the inner product... then he brings up the "canonical" representation of the inner product in R^N.

What, specifically, does he mean?  I see it a lot in matrix talk, but I'm never really sure what they mean.

Comment: Canonical in this sense means "standard"

Answer (score 1):

It is not the usual terminology.   "Canonical" has a well established use in linear algebra as a construction that is independent of a basis, or at least invariant with respect to different choices of basis.  The thing in the lecture slides (around 25min in the video) is ordinarily called the "standard" inner product associated to a basis, or the "Euclidean" inner product.